# Como usar 2 função updates no UserController em Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

Estou tentando adicionar imagem do perfil de usuário e também a carteira btc em um input. Se eu adiciono a carteira não consigo adicionar a img do perfil.
Vi que os dois usam a função update e por isso estou tendo conflito, se eu retirar a rota da carteira, a foto vai de boa, mas preciso dos 2 ok.

Minha rota:

```
Route::get('userp', 'UserController@index');
Route::post('userp', 'UserController@update');
```

Meu controlador da imagem perfil:

```
public function update_avatar(Request $request){
        if ($request->hasFile('avatar')){
            $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($avatar)->resize(300, 300)->save( public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename ));

            $user = Auth::user();
            $user->avatar = $filename;
            $user->save();
        }

        return view('userp', array('userp' => Auth::user()) );

}
```

Meu controlador da carteira:

```
public function update(Request $request) {

        $data = \Input::all();

        $valida = [
            'passaport' => 'passaport',
            'nascimento' => 'date',
            'bitzpayer_email' => 'email'
        ];

        if (!empty($data['password'])) {
            $valida = array_merge($valida, ['password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',]);
        }
        if (\Auth::user()->ativo == 0 && \Auth::user()->dataAtivacao == '0000-00-00') {
            $valida = array_merge($valida, ['pacote' => 'required|integer',]);
        }
        $validator = Validator::make($data, $valida);

        if ($validator->fails()) {

            return redirect('/userp')
                            ->withErrors($validator)
                            ->withInput();
        }
        if (!isset($data['saque'])) {

            if (!empty($data['bitzpayer_id'])) {
                if (!$this->checkAddress($data['bitzpayer_id'])) {
                    return redirect('/userp')->withErrors(['Invalid Wallet.']);
                }

            }

            $dados = [
                'bitzpayer_id' => @$data['bitzpayer_id'],
              ];
          } else {
            $dados = [
                'bitzpayer_id' => @$data['bitzpayer_id'],
             ];
        }

        if (\Auth::user()->ativo == 0 && \Auth::user()->dataAtivacao == '0000-00-00') {
            $dados['pacote'] = $data['pacote'];
        }
        if (!empty($data['password'])) {
            $senha = \DB::table('users')->where('id', \Auth::user()->id)->first()->password;
            if (\Hash::check($data['current_password'], $senha)) {
                $dados = array_merge($dados, ['password' => bcrypt($data['password']),]);
            } else {
                return redirect('userp')->withErrors(['Senha inválida, tente novamente.']);
            }
        }

        $user = \Auth::user()->update($dados);

        if ($user) { 

            return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Your bitcoin wallet has been updated successfully!');
        } else {
            return redirect('/userp')->withErrors(['Não foi possivel atualizar suas informações, tente novamente.']);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Você está com problema de lógica não é conflito.

Comment: me parece algo relativo ao submit, não estou encontrando outra forma de enviar sem que use eles

Comment: Atila dá pra enviar tudo isso em apenas uma requisição ... !!! não entendi o problema ainda é muito código para debugar!

Comment: @AtilaOliveira antes de tudo recomendo que leia isso https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/247791/como-trabalhar-com-valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-dados-no-laravel para trabalhar da melhor forma possível as validações do seu request e remove-los do controller, depois disso fica mais fácil resolver seu problema com a lógida do update, pois agora realmetne está mais complicado saber quando os `return` vão rodar simplesmente olhando o código

Comment: Cara tem muito código atoa vamos organizar esse código faz o seguinte 

$request->validate([]) passa os campos que vai validar e acaba com esse array de valida e o validator, e troca esse input::all() por $request->all();, como é um update precisa de outro parâmetro na function update que vem da URL que é o ID do usuário e você vai usar o $user = User::find($id); para fazer o update. Se não entendeu da um toque que faço o código como resposta.

Comment: Po kra muito obrigado msm, mas já havia resolvido e não sei como colocar esse post como resolvido, mas muito obrigado pela ajuda.